# Does Android 2.1+ support the ARM9 processor?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 2.1-eclair, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the minimum specifications for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34958/what-are-the-minimum-specifications-for-android)

I want to load Android 2+ (i.e 2.1 or 2.2) on an ARM9 processor, is it possible?  If I could have a comparative chart of which ARM processors are supported by which versions of Android it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not have a fixed minimum processor requirement, it's just recommended that the device be "fast enough".  See http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-2.1-cdd.pdf

Comment: Don't think this is going to be a minimum issue, there's a lot of Android devices out there on ARMv5, 6 & 7 processors. The Snapdragon SoC that runs HTC Desire, Nexus One etc is ARM 7 compatible. Could still be drivers/comptibility, don't know of any Android phones with ARMv9 yet.

Comment: Looks like one of the Archos tablets has an ARM9 chip: http://androidandme.com/2010/03/news/hands-on-the-archos-7-android-tablet/

Comment: If I recall correctly, the lower limit is ARM5. Freerunner has ARM4 and there are problems running Android native code--SDK assumes ARM5 during compilation.