# apps fail to access orientation & magnetic sensors

Tags: sensors, orientation, compass

I've just started using a Doogee Nova Y100X Android-based phone (it's android 5.0).

It seems that my apps can only access some of the phone's sensors: accelerometer seems to work, proximity and illumination as well - but not orientation and magnetometer. I tested using an app named Compass v0.1 and then with S Tools+.

Is this a hardware issue? A fundamental software issue due to the phone manufacturer? Or (hopefully) something I can fix with some kind of configuration?

Comment: Based from the description of [YouTube video review of this device](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RGlqUkK-5M), it only supports "Gravity Sensor Support, Light sensor Support, P-sensor Support", which is the same as your observation.. which makes me believe that this device **doesn't** have gyrometer and magnetometer. Have you tested it using [any sensor tester apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sensor&c=apps)?

Comment: @AndrewT.: It would be pretty strange if the device were missing such fundamental (I would think) sensors present on most(?) smartphones... I did use a sensor tester app,  [S Tools](https://github.com/naman14/S-Tools/blob/HEAD/README.md) ; but I'll try finding APKs for the ones you linked to (I don't use Google accounts so I can't get stuff from there.)

Comment: Well, from [this question about minimum hardware requirement](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34958/what-are-the-minimum-hardware-specifications-for-android/34959#34959), it refers to [Android CDC for Lollipop](https://source.android.com/compatibility/5.0/android-5.0-cdd.pdf), and there's a section for [sensors](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/5.0/android-5.0-cdd.pdf). Most sensors are recommended to have ("SHOULD"), but not a requirement ("MUST") (the categorization is defined on [RFC2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt))...

Comment: ... and it's not uncommon for Android devices not to have gyroscope and magnetometer. Many low-entry devices don't have (and thus, [cannot fully utilize Google Cardboard](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleCardboard/comments/30qu75/does_google_cardboard_work_at_all_without_a/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, as @AndrewT suggested, the device does not seem to have the extra sensors, physically.